SharePoint Column Formatting that detects matching words across all the items in the same column
I have a SharePoint list that has a specific column that is a "Multiple lines of text" type that is used to store a serial number or multiple serial numbers in a single column (separated by a space).
I want the JSON code to bold and render that text red when it detects a serial number already added to the list.
I assume this type of code would have to use a contains function of a string or create an array based on a space between values in the column. I'm just not familiar enough with JSON to go this deep into formatting.
I've used an IT tool to help write my code but was not successful when testing it out. I believe I read somewhere that I should not share code created by AI on this forum, so I won't. I looked on this website and searched other locations to find a solution but couldn't locate this question anywhere else.

Unfortunately, you will not be able to achieve this using SharePoint JSON formatting capabilities.
In column/view JSON formatting, you cannot access/use the column values from another list item/row.
You can only access the column values from the SAME list item/row like [$AnotherColumnFromSameRow].
Where AnotherColumnFromSameRow is internal name another column from same list item/row.
You can get the internal name of your list columns by following this article: How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?.
Similar thread: Highlight cell a color if there is a duplicate entry

Thanks for the details. it sounds like if I really want a "V LOOKUP" type of function, I'll have to turn to Power Automate. I already thought up a way to make that work, it's just the delay that's not fun. Thanks again! :)

Yes, Power Automate can achieve this. You also could consider to use Power Apps.
